# Android View shadow

Tags: android, shadow, dropshadow

I searched around, and I could not find a proper way to do this. I want to have the following shadow effects on my views:
[image]

[image]

To be honest, I do not know if this second one is done by applying shadow effect. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406524/how-to-set-shadow-to-a-view-in-android (check the highest vote answer, not the marked answer)

Comment: @DatVM, thanks, this seems like to do the trick, but I was thinking maybe there are built in tools in android sdk. For example, adding drop shadows for linear layouts by just adding some lines of code :P

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52954743/9640177 - adding shadow to vector drawable

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I know this question has already been answered but I want you to know that I found a `drawable` on `Android Studio` that is very similar to the pics you have in the question:
Take a look at this:

```
android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light"
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Hope it will be helpful

**Edit**

The option above is for the older versions of `Android Studio` so you may not find it. For newer versions:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Moreover, if you want to have your own custom shape, I suggest to use a drawing software like `Photoshop` and draw it.

[image]

Don't forget to save it as `.9.png` file (example: `my_background.9.png`)

Read the documentation: [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

**Edit 2**

An even better and less hard working solution is to use a `CardView` and set `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` to prevent views to overlap the borders:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:contentPadding="0dp">

    <!-- your layout stuff here -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Also make sure to have included the latest version in the `build.gradle`, current is

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, actually, it looks very similar. I also found "google card layout" for android, and they are pretty cool!

Comment: Awesome.  Just an FYI for future viewers, this is in `/<sdk-path>/extras/android/support`.

Comment: What about using a `cardView`

Answer (score 104):

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.6 and I couldn't find:

```
android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light"
```

so I found this instead:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: but we cannot add corner radius with it?!

Answer (score 41):

putting a background of `@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame`, gives shadow but you can't change background color nor border style, so it's better to benefit from the shadow of it, while still be able to put a background via layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--the shadow comes from here-->
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">

    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <!--whatever you want in the background, here i preferred solid white -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

save it in the drawable folder under say `shadow.xml`

to assign it to a view, in the xml layout file set the background of it

```
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
```

Comment: Did you check if it works? The second <item> doesn't do anything. I can't change it to transparent or rounded corners.

Comment: Among everything i have tried this is the only thing that works, thanks .

Comment: fantastic solution

Answer (score 36):

Create card_background.xml in the res/drawable folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Then add the following code to the element to which you want the card layout

```
android:background="@drawable/card_background"
```

the following line defines the color of the shadow for the card

```
<solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
```

Comment: This isn't really a shadow - because it doesn't fade. It's more like a border on two of the sides.

Comment: its not a shadow

Answer (score 32):

Use elevation property to achieve a shadow affect:

```
<View ...
    android:elevation="2dp"/>
```

This is only to be used past v21, check out this link: http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Comment: Best answer so far also working in Android 13

Comment: None of the solutions above worked for me, but yours did! And also it is the shortest one of all! Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

[CardView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView) gives you **true** shadow in android 5+ and it has a support library. Just wrap your view with it and you're done.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
     <MyLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It require the next dependency.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Comment: This is the only right answer, since only `CardView` also has varying shadow levels for different elevations in compat mode.

Comment: I recommend MaterialCardView since it's clearer and has more capabilities.

Answer (score 12):

This is may be late but for those who are still looking for answer for this I found a project on git hub and this is the only one that actually fit my needs. [android-materialshadowninepatch](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-materialshadowninepatch)

Just add this line on your build.gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.materialshadowninepatch:materialshadowninepatch:0.6.3'
```

cheers. thumbs up for the creator !
happycodings

Comment: Hey @ralphgabb, Does this still work good for you or you have a better solution for pre lollipop devices?

Comment: @Swapnil not sure if the AndroidX supports this now I am no longer supporting pre-Marshmallow devices though.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is stupidly hacky,
but if you want to support under v21, here are my achievements.

**rectangle_with_10dp_radius_white_bg_and_shadow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Shadow layers -->
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_1" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_2" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_3" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_4" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_5" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_6" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_7" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_8" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_9" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1.8dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/shadow_hack_level_10" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background layer -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**rectangle_with_10dp_radius_white_bg_and_shadow.xml** (v21)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**view_incoming.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_with_10dp_radius_white_bg_and_shadow"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="240dp"
    android:minHeight="240dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Hello World !" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is result:**

**Under v21** (this is which you made with xml)
[image]

**Above v21** (real elevation rendering)
[image]

- The one significant difference is it will occupy the inner space from the view so your actual content area can be smaller than **>= lollipop** devices.

Comment: It would be better to set real values of colors to see a result.

Answer (score 7):

If you are in need of the shadows properly to be applied then you have to do the following.

Consider this view, defined with a background drawable:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    ...
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect" />
```

The background drawable is defined as a rectangle with rounded corners:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

This is the recomended way of appying shadows check this out https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Shadows

Answer (score 6):

Create background drawable like this to show rounded shadow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp"
                     android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp"
                     android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp"
                     android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20d5d5d5" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp"
                     android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#30cbcbcb" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp"
                     android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#50bababa" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_100" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Please add description also for the code what you have provided.

Comment: Very nice xml only solution

Comment: Probably it's a good solution, but on a white background it looks like a light-gray rectangle (if set a thin border).

Answer (score 6):

This question may be old, but for anybody in future that wants a simple way to achieve complex shadow effects check out my library here 
https://github.com/BluRe-CN/ComplexView

Using the library, you can change shadow colors, tweak edges and so much more.
Here's an example to achieve what you seek for.

```
<com.blure.complexview.ComplexView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        app:radius="10dp"
        app:shadow="true"
        app:shadowSpread="2">

        <com.blure.complexview.ComplexView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:color="#fdfcfc"
            app:radius="10dp" />
    </com.blure.complexview.ComplexView>
```

To change the shadow color, use app:shadowColor="your color code".

Comment: your lib is awesome! Shadowing in Android is painful even in 2023.

Answer (score 4):

Use the elevation property for shadow affect:

```
<YourView
    ...
    android:elevation="3dp"/>
```

Comment: Using Elevation requires the device to run Lollipop.

Answer (score 1):

use this shape as background :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"/>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_200" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```