# Android: Applying rounded shape to a linear layout

Tags: android, layout, shapes, rounded-corners

I am gonna to create the a alert dialog box in android with rounded shape.
I follow many threads in this site. Create a shape.xml and place it drawables

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle"> 
 <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp"/> <solid android:color="#FFFF00"/>
```

And apply the above shape to the linearlayout. 
layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">

</LinearLayout>
```

However, there is still have a rectangle border and back color outside the dialog box. That is not what I want.
I have search for a long time I dont know how to fix it.
I aimed to make it transparent outside the corner of the dialog box layout. Thank you so much!

Screen Shot: http://postimg.org/image/3xbnmquyt/

Comment: can you post that image?

Comment: Just like [http://openclipart.org/people/rg1024/rg1024_set_of_eight_rounded_shapes.svg](this) The left of the middle one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the shape you want I found the default one on `Android Studio`, this:

```
android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light"
```

Apply it to your `LinearLayout`, It is exatcly what you're talikng about and you don't need to create other `xml` files in the `drawables`. To see how It looks like see my answer here:
[Android View shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow/21445593#21445593)

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I sorry that I may confuse you from the code above. I actually want to make the shape like this [link] (http://openclipart.org/detail/27891/set-of-eight-rounded-shapes-by-rg1024-27891). I end up get the correct shape but there is a black color outside the corner. Hope you get what I mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the stroke tag because it is used for creating the border. Also you shouldn't use gradient and solid together because they exclude one another.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: Yes, I need to create a border align with the rounded corner. But there is a black color outside the corner now. I want to make it transparent.

Comment: Ok, it would be much easier if you post the code of your layout xml but I think you should put your LinearLayout in another layout that has the same dimensions but not the rounded corner and than set the color of this container layout to transparent or even better set the same color as the background is.

Comment: I have edit my post and the code attached. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I think that the problem is with transparent background of the container linearlayout. If you know what color should be in the background put it instead of @android:color/transparent. If you don't, try removing container layout or programmatically in the code set it's color when and where you use it.

Comment: Ok, I removed the container layout and it got a same result. I am using setContentView method to open this layout. Am I correct to call this layout? Thank you for your patient to answer me a question. I am so new for Android Dev.><

Comment: The dark color is the color of the Android background. Put back the container and set it's background color to color that you want.

Comment: So, can the color of the container set to transparent? It is so wired to hv a dark color arround the alert dialog

Comment: You can set it to transparent but if you use ths component somewhere where you don't have and other view beneath it it while be dark beacase than it will use the default Android color which is dark.