# Shadow round corners Android

Tags: android

how can i make a shadow for round corners? I tried it with views for the bottom, right an the corner, but that works not really :D 
I tried this xml for the corner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#404040"
      android:centerColor="#DBDBDB"
      android:endColor="@color/shadow_end"
      android:angle="315"
      >
  </gradient>
  <corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
   android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Is it good to use views for shadows? What you are using?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply draw a `9-patch` image with `Photoshop` drawing the shadows and put it into the `drawable` folders and set this in your `View` in xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_9patch_image"
```

I always do it by using `Photoshop`. For more details see this: [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Or you can check in the default `Android Studio` drawables and see if there's one that you like. Check my answer here: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow/21445593#21445593)