# Android L Elevation Effect in Pre L (only using elevation property)

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working on an App and want to have an elevation effect on `ImageView` or any `View` (!CardView in support library) in Pre L APIs. But i'm not able to achieve that what i tried is used `android:elevation` property but it doesn't have any effect (No elevation).

I can't find any API, if someone point out any documentation to achieve this in Pre L or any snippet from Support library is highly appreciated.

Comment: Elevation is not available on pre L.

Comment: i read this 'You can also set this from code using getElevation()/setElevation() (with shims in ViewCompat)'
here: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html

Comment: @AdrianoCelentano Thats correct but it has no effect on devices pre-5.0

Comment: `yourAppNs:elevation="4dp"` will be OK

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set views in 3D shape, `View.setElevation()` and `View.setTranslationZ()` is a good idea.

But unfortunately, the two attributes and methods are introduced since Android API 21. So, you can't use them on pre-L or API 21- devices.

But, there is still a way to custom your views' shadows and outlines.

The bounds of a view's background drawable determine the default shape of its shadow. Outlines represent the outer shape of a graphics object and define the ripple area for touch feedback.

Consider this view, defined with a background drawable:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/myview"
...
android:elevation="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/myrect" />
```

The background drawable is defined as a rectangle with rounded corners:

```
<!-- res/drawable/myrect.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

The view casts a shadow with rounded corners, since the background drawable defines the view's outline. Providing a custom outline overrides the default shape of a view's shadow.

To define a custom outline for a view in your code:

1. Extend the `ViewOutlineProvider` class.
2. Override the `getOutline()` method.
3. Assign the new outline provider to your view with the
   `View.setOutlineProvider()` method.

You can create oval and rectangular outlines with rounded corners using the methods in the `Outline` class. The default outline provider for views obtains the outline from the view's background. To prevent a view from casting a shadow, set its outline provider to `null`.

Hopefully it helps.

**P.S.:**
`yourAppNs:elevation="4dp"` will be a good idea if you are using ***android-design-library***.

Comment: Did you import **android-design-library** and set `xmlns:yourAppNs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` on you root view?

Comment: yes of course but it doesn't have any effect on my view so I worked this around from java code using the ViewCompat.setElevation(myView, 5)

Comment: Does `ViewCompat.setElevation(myView, 5)` work well?

Answer (score 1):

- ViewCompat.setElevation()/getElevation() doesnt work on pre Lollipop.
- There isnt anything worth checking out at the support library, at least until version 21.1.1
- As for creating an elevation effect by yourself
  take a look at
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow)