# Elevation attribute for lower api

Tags: android, android-layout

How to use elevation xml attribute for api lower than 21 without using cardview. I want to use this attriburte in recycleview for lower api.

Comment: There is no such attribute for lower api levels. It is supported from 5.0 onwards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android L Elevation Effect in Pre L (only using elevation property)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468087/android-l-elevation-effect-in-pre-l-only-using-elevation-property)