# Bottom shadow to ListPopupWindow android

Tags: android, listview, dropshadow, android-popupwindow

I am using ListPopupWindow and want to add bottom shadow to it. Below is my code -

```
    listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
    listPopupWindow.setContentWidth(500);
    listPopupWindow.setDropDownGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT);
    listPopupWindow.setSelection(mSelectedPos);
    listPopupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            listPopupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Listpopupadapter adapter = new Listpopupadapter(mContext, mGameSortList, GameName, mFilterStr,mListener,Gravity.RIGHT);
    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(adapter);
    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(mRightTV);
    listPopupWindow.setForceIgnoreOutsideTouch(true);
    listPopupWindow.show();
```

how to show bottom shadow when popup is display.

TIA

Comment: Refer this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow

Answer (score 1):

```
listPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
```

Comment: little description od solution may help to understand concept behind problem.