# Android: how to have the same drop shadow like Instagram?

Tags: android, drawable, linear-gradients

I would like to have the same drop shadow like **Instagram**.

[image]

So I've created this drawable, but it's not totally the same. Could you help me guys please?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerColor="#22232323"
        android:endColor="#77232323"
        android:angle="90"/>

</shape>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about `android:elevation="4dp"`?

Comment: I don't want to use elevation, because I must support from SDK 4.1. Simple solution with this drawable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android View shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow)