# How to add shadow to a imageview?

Tags: android, border, shadow

I'm trying to add a border and a shadow to my imageview, which is placed in a ConstraintLayout.
I tried to use a 9 patch image, but it not work at all!

Below, is the layout that contains the imageview.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_google_cards_media_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,400:576"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_vertical_start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/default_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_main_image" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I wish to have something similar to the image below.
[image: Result Expected]

Comment: this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445593/1320616

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal I tried that, but it only put shadow on top and bottom. I'm thinking that constraint is causing that.