# How to add drop shadows to png formatted icons in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, shadow, figma

There is a drop shadow feature in the Figma.I have used the same in one of my search icon.

[image: figma search icon]

I want to do the same in the xml file in android studio.

[image: xml search icon]

How to add this drop shadow to the icon in xml in android studio ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21211870/ check this